# How to find cells in two dimensional array at a k distance from a source?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

What algorithm can I implement to take all positions at a set distance from a source on a two dimensional array? I want something that is fast since I need this to be updated every frame of a game. My idea was to iterate with an int i from -k to +k, adding i to position_source_x and add(for positions above the source) or subtract(for positions bellow the source) to position_source_y the remaining distance k - abs(i).
So the formula would be array[x+i][y+k-abs(i)] and array[i][y-k+abs(i)] where i takes values from -k to +k. But since I need to do this for multiple distances every frame, I thought i could optimize this. Any suggestions? I need to draw the cells which have different distances with different opacity.

Comment: How big is your array? If your array is not very big, you are probably best off by precalculating an array of opacities.

Comment: So ~6 simple arithmetic operations per cell you need to return? That should be fast enough for most, if not all, applications. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).